# Javascript: How to extend dom property while keeping original reference?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change a property like Element.scrollTop. I would like to return a number that is a modification of the original number

```
var descriptorWithChanges =
{
    get: function () {
        alert("scrollTop accessor " + this.scrollTop);
        var originalScrollTop = this.scrollTop
        return (originalScrollTop - 10);
    }
};
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "scrollTop", descriptorWithChanges);
```

The problem is that i get error: too much recursion. What is the correct way of storing reference to originalScrollTop ?